# Python automating text data files into csv

Tags: python, automation

I am trying to automate a process where in a specific folder, there are multiple text files following the same data format/structure.  In the text files, the data is separated by a comma.  I want to be able to output all of these text files into one cumulative csv file.  This is what I currently have, and seem to be stuck where I am because of my lack of python knowledge.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import glob

def get_site_files():
    sites = defaultdict(list)
    for fname in glob.glob('*.txt'):

csv_out = csv.writer(open('out.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')

f = open('myfile.txt')
for line in f:
  vals = line.split(',')
  csv_out.writerow()
f.close()
```

EDIT: bringing up comments: I want to make sure that all of the text files are read, not just only myfile.txt.

Also, if I could combine them all into one large .txt file and then I could make those into a csv that would be great too, I just am not sure the exact way to do this.

Comment: What is not working?  You can use a csv.reader as well, so you don't encounter read bugs by just splitting on comma.

Comment: If I understand correctly the data in the text files is already what you want, so why not just merge the text files into one file?

Comment: @bmorgan21 I am not sure how to make sure that the csv writer will go through all the text files?  I originally started with just the csv writer part, as it will work on myfile.txt.  How will it know to open all the text files in the folder to correlate them into one place?

Comment: @joente there are many many small text files, and as more data comes in this will get larger.  Is there a way in python to do this? Maybe I could have two scripts to do the work I want, one to merge all the text files together and one to output to csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little bit of reordering of your code.

```
import csv
import glob

def get_site_files():
    with open('out.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        csv_out = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
        for fname in glob.glob('*.txt'):
            with open(fname) as f:
                for line in f:
                    vals = line.split(',')
                    csv_out.writerow(vals)

get_site_files()
```

But since they are all in the same format you can just concatenate them:

```
import glob
with ('out.csv', 'w') as fout:
    for fname in glob.glob('*.txt'):
        with open(fname, 'r') as fin:
            fout.write(fin.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try a different way:

I used os.listdir() once. That gives you a List of all the files in your directory. In combination with os.path.join you can manage all *.csv files in a certain directory.

Some additional Information can be found in the reference: [os](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

So I would just loop through all the files in the directory (searching for them ending on ".csv"), for each of them, store each line in a list as a string, separate the strings by the colums delimiter, make "," to "." in the left strings and concatenate the strings again. Afterwards push each line of the list to the outputfile you wish to use

I highly recommend the [python standard library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/) for information about the total functionality of python to newbies ;)

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the code above to covert text files to csv and get working code to convert all csv files in a folder to one text files appending all csv files. Works great.

import glob
    import csv

```
def get_site_files():
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
       csv_out = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
       for fname in glob.glob('*.csv'):
           with open(fname) as f:
               for line in f:
                   vals = line.split(',')
                   csv_out.writerow(vals)enter code here
```